# Web hosting how to prevent user from navigating my website folders?

Tags: php, security, hosting

I don't want the user to type in the URL my website and type a folder and this folder open to him..
I want the user only to top my index.php page and navigate from it to my links only not folders.

Comment: @Marc B please tell me where is it because i didn't find it

Comment: @AhmedEasamAE - Start by looking at the accepted answer to the linked question